# Basic carousel for an horizontal menu using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have an horizontal menu containing too many elements to be displayed on the same space. I would like to create a carousel effect so that the container would horizontally translate to one side when the user click on a directional arrow.

```css
.container {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 height: 70px;
 width: 420px;
  border: 1px solid  black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

 a {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 margin: 0 10px;
 min-width: 50px;
 min-height: 50px;
 border: 0.1px solid tomato;
}

 #left, #right {
 border: 1px solid orange;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px 60px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

* {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <a>1</a>
 <a>2</a>
 <a>3</a>
 <a>4</a>
 <a>5</a>
 <a>6</a>
 <a>7</a>
 <a>8</a>
 <a>9</a>
 <a>10</a>
 <a>11</a>
 <a>12</a>
 <a>13</a>
 <a>14</a>
</div>

<div id="left">left arrow</div>
<div id="right">right arrow</div>
```

How can I animate this with jQuery/CSS so that upon clicking `right` the current elements would translate to the left so the next elements are displayed ?
I was thinking of using translate(%) but the width of the div relies on the number of elements in the container so it varies... 
Also if there is only 2 elements to be displayed I would have to adjust the animation.

I'm a bit lost so any help is welcome !

Comment: Please share what you tried to achieve your need.

Comment: What I tried was adding a class `-webkit-transform:translate(-420px,0);` (or +420px) when clicking an arrow on another container but that was too inconsistent and I couldn't not adjust it when the remaining elements took less than 420px of space.  I don't think this was the right approach to the problem

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like this. I added an inner container which can move inside the main container.

I doesn't check yet if the end of start is reached. Checking whether or not the first/last child element is visible might be a way to cover.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#right").on("click", function() {
    var l = $(".inner").css("left");
    l = Number(l.substring(0, l.length - 2)) - 420;
    $(".inner").css("left", l + "px");
  });
  
  $("#left").on("click", function() {
    var l = $(".inner").css("left");
    l = Number(l.substring(0, l.length - 2)) + 420;
    $(".inner").css("left", l + "px");
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  height: auto;
  width: 420px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 1em 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.inner {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
}

a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 10px;
  min-width: 50px;
  min-height: 50px;
  border: 0.1px solid tomato;
}

#left,
#right {
  border: 1px solid orange;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px 60px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <a>1</a>
    <a>2</a>
    <a>3</a>
    <a>4</a>
    <a>5</a>
    <a>6</a>
    <a>7</a>
    <a>8</a>
    <a>9</a>
    <a>10</a>
    <a>11</a>
    <a>12</a>
    <a>13</a>
    <a>14</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="left">left arrow</div>
<div id="right">right arrow</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help ! Indeed this is a clean way to do it. Checking if the last child is visible and stopping the translate animation could work, i can maybe add 2 fake elements of 1x1px dimension "wrapping" the inner div so the animation doesn't stop when the last child is only partially visible ! I will try some things out and update if necessary, thanks !